# Removing linebreak after first value in a .csv string using VB

Tags: vb.net, csv, replace, line-breaks, streamwriter

I have a small function that creates a .csv file from strings stored in a Data Grid.

```
Dim rowcount As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For m As Integer = 0 To rowcount
            Dim strrowvalue As String = ""
            strrowvalue += CStr(DataGridView1.Rows(m).Cells(0).Value)
            For n As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                    strrowvalue += "," + "0"
                End If
                If DataGridView1.Rows(m).Cells(n).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                    strrowvalue += "," + "0"
                Else
                    strrowvalue += "," + CStr(DataGridView1.Rows(m).Cells(n).Value)
                End If
            Next

            If m <> rowcount Then
                streamwriter.WriteLine(strrowvalue)
            End If
        Next
```

However after the first value a linebreak is inserted. This causes Excel and other programs to place the first value on line 1, then the rest of the values of that line are placed on line 2.

Example:

1. 100 ,
2. 555,333,333,666,777
3. 200 ,
4. 444,555,453,345,778

It should be:

1. 100,555,333,333,666,777
2. 200,444,555,453,345,778

Any ideas?

EDIT: Question has been modified to show that it was a linebreak that was being inserted into the string, not a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not clear from your code where the space comes from, and the best way for getting rid of the space is probably to prevent it from ever occurring in the first place.

In addition, the space will *not* cause Excel to add a line break (I’ve just tested it to make sure). In fact, Excel silently swallows the space. If a line break is inserted in your case, that suggests that the character isn’t a whitespace but something else.

Apart from that, your code for removing whitespace works. You probably forgot to assign the result to a variable:

```
strrowvalue = strrowvalue.Replace(" ", "")
```

Edit: since it’s apparently a carriage return character rather than a space, use this:

```
strrowvalue = strrowvalue.Replace(vbCr, "")
```

Or, if it’s a full Windows-style line break:

```
strrowvalue = strrowvalue.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
```

If neither of these works (weird!), try this:

```
strrowvalue = strrowvalue.Replace(vbLf, "")
```

In other news, you should use a `StringBuilder` here instead, it will perform much better than lots of repeated string concatenations.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and I'm still getting the space. Notepad++ tells me there is a CR linebreak after the first value... not sure how that is happening.

Comment: @Mellonjollie See updated answer. A linebreak makes more sense. ;-)

Comment: Getting the same results with the String Builder too. The linebreak is coming directly from the DataGrid, but I don't know why it's only the first value. The DataGrid displays the results correctly, and so does the SQL StoredProc it's linked to.

Comment: @Mellonjollie Yes, the `StringBuilder` is for performance, not to fix this particular error. But just remove the line break with the same method as the space.

Comment: +1 for StringBuilder, as well as the analysis on how Excel is processing the text.

Comment: `strrowvalue = strrowvalue.Replace(vbCr, "")` worked. Thanks so much for giving me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of line break is being inserted, I'd update this line to one of the following:

```
strrowvalue += CStr(DataGridView1.Rows(m).Cells(0).Value).Replace(vbCrLf,"")
```

-- or --

```
strrowvalue += CStr(DataGridView1.Rows(m).Cells(0).Value).Replace(vbCr,"")
```

-- or --

```
strrowvalue += CStr(DataGridView1.Rows(m).Cells(0).Value).Replace(vbLf,"")
```